# Проблема с манипуляцией файлами на сервере

Tags: php, linux

Есть сервер на linux , там стоит сайт написанный на php.
Есть скрипты которые создают обычные txt файлы, и скрипты которые копируют эти файлы в другие папки, все это реализовано на php.

Возникла проблема - если папка с правами 755 или файл с 644 - ** failed to open stream: Permission denied**

А папок и файлов очень много, и менять им атрибуты не лучший вариант.
Как можно обойти это?

P.S. до этого сайт стоял на хостинге - с файлами и папками с такими атрибутами все работало.

Comment: Потому что на хостинге php выполнялся под другим пользователем.

Comment: Если вы настраиваете сервер самостоятельно, то можете попробовать поместить вашего пользователя в одну группу с пользователем, который выполняет соответствующие скрипты. Если это обычный виртуальный хостинг - то тут единственный вариант, менять права доступа на 777.

Comment: @KAGGDesign как выполнять php от главного root ?

Comment: Не надо от root, это совершенно неправильно и небезопасно. Пользователь php задается в файле www.conf. Этот же пользователь должен быть владельцем папки сайта. Тогда все будет работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой бы не был могучий PHP, если сервер говорит что прав нет, то PHP уже ничего не сделает.
Вы можете двумя строчками поменять всем файлам и папкам права

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Только измените var/www на ваш каталог.

Можно еще выдать для PHP права максимальные, но это я бы не рекомендовал.